# Tor launcher error message recieved

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have recently installed tor. I cannot open the browser as I am receiving the following message:

unable to save tor setting
Unable to set option: Failed to bind one of the listener ports

Comment: What operating system are you running Tor on? Have you made any manual changes to the `torrc`? and can you provide a full copy of the log output?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the tor launcher is trying to start the background tor process before opening the browser, but the tor process is already running. I recommend stopping the orphaned tor process and then trying again. There are probably better ways to shut down tor depending on how the launcher starts it but you can try running this command:

```
pkill tor
```

Or just restart your computer.

Windows version: [I can not start downloading Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16484/i-can-not-start-downloading-tor/16493#16493)